# Pulling a json from url into a dataframe error

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

Looking here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40538/automatically-get-ishares-etf-holdings/40610?noredirect=1#comment63646_40610 it seems like I can point to a url that has a file, in order to pull it into a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239705/ishares-phlx-semiconductor-etf/1467271812596.ajax?fileType=csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=10)    
print(df.head())
```

I tried doing the same for a json type file:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/etf-product-list/1522815705927.ajax?fileType=json'
df = pd.read_json(url)
print(df.head()
```

However, it is throwing a `ValueError: Expected object or value`. I tried adding `lines=True` and other variants but no luck.
How can I pull this json as a dataframe?

You can see how it actually looks by going to https://www.ishares.com/us/products/etf-product-list and clicking "Download" (this generates a .xls), or in your browser just typing https://www.ishares.com/us/products/etf-product-list/1522815705927.ajax?fileType=json. The reason I dont pick `fileType=csv` or `xls` is because `csv` returns an unexpected output with lots of JS code, and `xls` returns HTTP 500 error.

Comment: Is the response  a valid json?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Pasting this in the browser downloads the file to your computer `https://www.ishares.com/us/products/etf-product-list/1522815705927.ajax?fileType=json`

Comment: You need a link that generates the json in browser. this is just a link to download the file. I don't believe it's returning the json to python, rather just a status code of 200

Comment: @Jaba Do you see a different way to of downloading this file (in whatever format) so that I can load data to dataframe?

Comment: My simple guess/workaround is to allow it to download then open the file from the `Downloads` directory

Comment: @Jaba Unfortunately I am trying to incorporate this within a larger process, so manually downloading it would not work for me (if it can be downloaded with Python code that would certainly work! just not sure how)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the reason is for the error but here's a workaround using the requests library:

```
import requests
from json import loads
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/etf-product-list/1522815705927.ajax?fileType=json'
json_dict = loads(requests.get(url).content)

#parse headers
headers=[]
for header in json_dict['columns']:
    headers.append(header['name'])

df = pd.DataFrame(json_dict['data'], columns=headers)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you try running this? I get a ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded unfortunately

Comment: That was the exact issue I was trying to workaround. See this link literally downloads the JSON file, it doesn't return JSON just most likely a status code of 200 saying that the request was made.

Comment: I ran it again and it worked fine for me. I'm using requests 2.21.0 and json 2.0.9